# SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, express

I have used map to merge 2 arrays by creating the code below.

```
var result2 = data.map(k=>(
  stAttendance = attendance.find(p=>p.StudentName._id==k._id),
  ({...k, Present:stAttendance?.Present ?? 0, absent:stAttendance?.absent ?? 0, extra:stAttendance?.extra ?? 0})
));

console.log(result2);
```

This code works perfectly when I use it in the script tag of an HTML page.
As soon as I put it in my Node JS router.get function it starts giving following error

```
  ({...k, Present:stAttendance?.Present ?? 0, absent:stAttendance?.absent ?? 0, extra:stAttendance?.extra ?? 0})
                                       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
```

Anyone knows what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Probably you're running a node.js version that doesn't support the `?.` syntax yet in `Present:stAttendance?.Present`.

Comment: What's node version which you are using?

Comment: I am using Node 12.13.0

Answer (score 2):

Per [node.green](https://node.green/#ES2020-features-optional-chaining-operator-----), even node.js v14 does not yet support the optional chaining `?.` operator.  Though, when I test nodejs v14.4 myself, it does work for me.

Similarly with the [nullish coalescing operator](https://node.green/#ES2020-features--nullish-coalescing-operator-----) `??`.

MDN seems to claim that both are supported as of node.js 14.0 so they would not work in your v12.

If it is not supported in your version of nodejs, you can write the code the same way you always would have before these new operators.  Just break your code into multiple steps and check to see if properties properly exist with conditional statements.

Comment: Oh, Thanks for the link it seems none of the NodeJS versions support ?. operators.
What can I do to replace my code?

Comment: @creativated - Even MDN says it requires node v14.  I just installed node v14.4 on my laptop here and the optional chaining operator `?.` does work for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the existing code for optional chaining and nullish coalescing with the below code.

```js
var result2 = data.map(k=>(
  stAttendance = attendance.find(p=>p.StudentName._id==k._id) || {},
  ({...k, Present: stAttendance.Present || 0, absent: stAttendance.absent || 0, extra:stAttendance.extra || 0})
));
```

Comment: This code gives me an error Untitled-7.html:22 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Present' of undefined
https://jsfiddle.net/creativated/qx0gbmzs/

If I remove the third student from data array then it works fine

Comment: In the fiddle I could see there's a small difference in the code which I have provided and the one which is being tried. It's coded as `attendance.find(p=>p.StudentName._id==k._id)`  whereas it should be `attendance.find(p=>p.StudentName._id==k._id) || {}`